# Run 8086 programs in dos using simple os other than any special software

Tags: ms-dos, 8086

I know to run 8086 using MASM & 8086 emulator, but how to run 8086 programs in dos without any special software.

Comment: Do you have a real machine running DOS (which machine, which DOS?), or just an emulator (which emulator)?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you mean MS-DOS or another DOS?  We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: Your question is *very unclear* - Are you asking how to get a program from anywhere onto a DOS machine?

Comment: What is considered 'special software' in your question?

Comment: One possible interpretation of your question would be how to build and execute a program written in assembly language using only MS-DOS and tools included with it (which is achievable using the [DEBUG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_(command)) program that is supplied with MS-DOS)

Comment: Load the program into memory and jump to it.  If you write it to a flat binary file linked to run at 0x100 and put a .com extension on it, this is fairly trivial, just type the file name.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your question is about working with 8086 assembly language programs, without using third party software.

Look at the DEBUG.EXE program that is part of all practical MS-DOS distributions -it does contain a simple assembler and the needed auxiliary tools.